# Getting 500 error from my mvc application on azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, model-view-controller, azure-web-app-service

I SOLVED PROBLEM AND I ADDED MY SOLUTION TO PROBLEM AS A REPLY TO THIS POST.

I started to learn asp.net mvc and entity framework. I finished a site and tried to upload azure for sharing with other people. When I uploaded it I get 500 error and I looked out for solving this problem. But I couldn't found correct answer to my problem in stack overflow and msdn and I don't know what is the real error, I couldn't spot it in azure logs or in kudu. I tried republish my project, publishing to different web app service and the result did not change. I am trying to solve this problem for 2 days and I couldn't find correct answer yet. I can reach static pages like my error pages in html/aspx forms or dummy page I recently created but when I try to reach a mvc view I am getting error. Also when I got 404 error display of the error site is wrong and I am getting 404 errors for images and scripts in 404 page as well. Could you help me? I am adding what I show in log stream as well.

```
2018-07-19T08:45:22  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2018-07-19T08:45:27  PID[9284] Information Unpacking resources...
2018-07-19T08:45:27  PID[9284] Information 07-19 08:45:27 Information: Executing Application Insights Profiler agent version 2.4.60711.2 with arguments: 
2018-07-19T08:45:27  PID[9284] Information 07-19 08:45:27 Information: Detected an Azure App Service sandbox.
2018-07-19T08:45:27  PID[9284] Information 07-19 08:45:27 Information: Detected an Azure App Service sandbox.
2018-07-19T08:45:27  PID[9284] Information 07-19 08:45:27 Information: Minimum version enabled on machine: 
2018-07-19T08:45:27  PID[9284] Information 07-19 08:45:27 Information: Instrumentation key: 
2018-07-19T08:45:27  PID[9284] Information 07-19 08:45:27 Information: Application Insights Profiler endpoint: https://agent.azureserviceprofiler.net
2018-07-19T08:45:27  PID[9284] Information 07-19 08:45:27 Information: Application Insights endpoint: default
2018-07-19T08:45:27  PID[9284] Information 07-19 08:45:27 Information: Runtime Environment: Antares
2018-07-19T08:45:27  PID[9284] Information 07-19 08:45:27 Information: Support files: D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\ApplicationInsightsProfiler2\e1izfqr5.4is\spsupport
2018-07-19T08:45:27  PID[9284] Information 07-19 08:45:27 Information: Providing usage data (to opt out set the AppSettings ApplicationInsightsProvideUsageTelemetryData with the value "false"): True
2018-07-19T08:45:27  PID[9284] Information 07-19 08:45:27 Information: Engine mode: Immediate
2018-07-19T08:45:28  PID[9284] Information 07-19 08:45:28 Error: Unexpected exception in agent main process. Details: Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Utilities.AppIdNotFoundException: Unable to find AppId for iKey: 
2018-07-19T08:45:28  PID[9284] Information    at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Utilities.AppInsightsProfileFetcher.<FetchProfileAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
2018-07-19T08:45:28  PID[9284] Information --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2018-07-19T08:45:28  PID[9284] Information    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
2018-07-19T08:45:28  PID[9284] Information    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2018-07-19T08:45:28  PID[9284] Information    at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.DiagnosticsAgent.Program.GetApplicationInsightsAppId(String instrumentationKey, String appInsightsEndpoint)
2018-07-19T08:45:28  PID[9284] Information    at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.DiagnosticsAgent.Program.Main(String[] cmdArgs)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 sandboxproc.exe C:\DWASFiles\Sites\ECommerceFurkan\Temp\applicationhost.config True True
2018-07-19T08:45:30 env XPROC_TYPENAME=Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Transformers.ApplicationHost.SiteExtensionHelper, Microsoft.Web.Hosting, Version=7.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
2018-07-19T08:45:30 env XPROC_METHODNAME=Transform
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Start 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites' site extension transform
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 6, 21)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'configuration' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 7, 14)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'system.webServer' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Inserted 'runtime' element
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 8, 29)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'runtime' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 9, 227)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='MicrosoftAppInsights_ManagedHttpModulePath']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 10, 164)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='MicrosoftAppInsights_ManagedHttpModuleType']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertOrAppendAttribute (transform line 11, 270)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='DOTNET_ADDITIONAL_DEPS']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertOrAppendAttribute
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertOrAppendAttribute (transform line 12, 160)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='DOTNET_SHARED_STORE']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertOrAppendAttribute
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertOrAppendAttribute (transform line 13, 111)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertOrAppendAttribute
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 15, 78)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='COR_ENABLE_PROFILING']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 16, 107)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='COR_PROFILER']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 17, 206)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='COR_PROFILER_PATH_32']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 18, 206)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='COR_PROFILER_PATH_64']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 19, 130)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='MicrosoftInstrumentationEngine_Host']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 20, 244)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='MicrosoftInstrumentationEngine_HostPath_32']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 21, 244)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='MicrosoftInstrumentationEngine_HostPath_64']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 22, 82)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 23, 111)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='CORECLR_PROFILER']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 24, 210)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='CORECLR_PROFILER_PATH_32']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 25, 210)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='CORECLR_PROFILER_PATH_64']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 29, 181)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='MicrosoftProductionDiagnostics_RuntimeFolder']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 31, 111)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='MicrosoftProductionDiagnostics_DisableInstrumentation']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 33, 112)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='MicrosoftProductionDiagnostics_GrantException_Websites']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 36, 102)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='MicrosoftInstrumentationEngine_LogLevel']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 46, 372)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='MicrosoftInstrumentationEngine_ConfigPath32_Private']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 47, 372)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='MicrosoftInstrumentationEngine_ConfigPath64_Private']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 54, 23)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'location' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 55, 16)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/modules
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'system.webServer' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Inserted 'modules' element
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 60, 16)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'system.webServer' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Inserted 'rewrite' element
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 61, 33)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'rewrite' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 62, 81)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables/add[@name='HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'allowedServerVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 63, 70)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables/add[@name='HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'allowedServerVariables' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 66, 16)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite/rules
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'rewrite' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 67, 75)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'rules' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertOrAppendAttribute (transform line 81, 50)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite/outboundRules
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'rewrite' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertOrAppendAttribute
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 82, 97)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite/outboundRules/rule
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'outboundRules' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 87, 96)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite/outboundRules/rule
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'outboundRules' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 92, 26)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite/outboundRules/preConditions
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'outboundRules' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 93, 89)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite/outboundRules/preConditions/preCondition[@name='IsApplicationInsightsEnabled']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'preConditions' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 100, 89)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite/outboundRules/preConditions/preCondition[@name='NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'preConditions' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 106, 20)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite/providers
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'rewrite' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing RemoveAll (transform line 107, 69)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite/providers/provider[@name='EnvVarProvider']
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'provider' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Removed 'provider' element
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'provider' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Removed 'provider' element
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing RemoveAll
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 108, 21)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/rewrite/providers/provider
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'providers' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Inserted 'provider' element
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2018-07-19T08:45:30 StartSection Executing InsertOrAppendAttribute (transform line 112, 61)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 on /configuration/location[@path='ECommerceFurkan']/system.webServer/urlCompression
2018-07-19T08:45:30 Applying to 'system.webServer' element (no source line info)
2018-07-19T08:45:30 EndSection Done executing InsertOrAppendAttribute
2018-07-19T08:45:31 Successful 'D:\home\SiteExtensions\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites\applicationHost.xdt' site extension transform
2018-07-19T08:45:31 sandboxproc.exe complete successfully. Elapsed = 1010.00 ms
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS Detailed Error - 500.0 - Internal Server Error</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;} 
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} 
.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} 
pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} 
ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;} 
ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} 
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;} 
.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} 
legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} 
legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; 
font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;} 
a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;} 
a:hover{text-decoration:none;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} 
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;} 
h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0; 
}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif; 
color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2; 
}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;} 
.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} 
.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0; 
}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%; 
}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden; 
}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF; 
background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal; 
font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right; 
}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;} 
table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;} 
td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;} 
th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;} 
thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%; 
}#details-right th{width:20%;} 
table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{} 
.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;} 
.clear{clear:both;} 
.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;} 
--> 
</style> 

</head> 
<body> 
<div id="content"> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<h3>HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error</h3> 
<h4>The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.</h4> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.</li>    <li>IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.</li>    <li>IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.</li>     <li>The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.</li>   <li>The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.</li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.</li>     <li>Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.</li>  <li>Verify the permissions for the DLL.</li>    <li>Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.</li>  <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4> 
<div id="details-left"> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ManagedPipelineHandler</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x00000000</td></tr> 

</table> 
</div> 
<div id="details-right"> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;http://ECommerceFurkan:80/</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D:\home\site\wwwroot</td></tr> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr> 

</table> 
<div class="clear"></div> 
</div> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4> 
This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error. 
<p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=500,0,0x00000000,14393">View more information &raquo;</a></p> 
<p>Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:</p> 


</fieldset> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Have you successfully published on your local iis?

Comment: Yeah the site works fine in my local iis and I get no error. But when I uploaded to azure I get 500 error always

Comment: How do you publish your website to azure?

Comment: At first I downloaded publish profile from azure portal and select project publish on visual studio and I used import as a method. But I couldn't solve problem and then I tried by Microsoft azure app service method in visual studio publish method. But result stayed the same. Both of them gave 500 error. I tried it with a new mvc project and it worked fine on azure by the same way.

Comment: Few Questions: 
Can you share your web config?  
what is happening on your home page? 
What add-in / nuget packages are you using? Are those DLL's getting shipped with your deployment to Azure?

Comment: Well I reviewed my web config few hours ago and decided to write connection strings by my hand instead of letting it to azure and site works just fine now. I don't know what was wrong with azure's connection strings but somehow they restiricted my site to reach db with admin account, even viewing was not possible. thanks you to with your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem with writing connection strings with my hand. If anyone has the same trouble I recommend them to try connecting to azure database from your local computer with creating new server connection and then implement it to your local project. If the site works fine with new connections it will work fine on azure too.